# Using Torch installation in one Linux system on another linux system

Tags: deep-learning, torch

I have a very amusing and troubling problem. On my home system, I can install Torch7 and use it.

I do not have administrative privileges on my office system. Unfortunately, many dependencies of Torch such as readline are hence not satisfied. Is it possible that I can use the torch installation of my system, by copying it to my office system ? What would I have to do for that if that were possible ?

To detail my problem, here is what happens when I install torch7 on my office system.

I installed ncurses and readline libraries in my home folder. When I install the readline library, (after installing ncurses), it gives me undefined reference problem at the time of make install like this :

libreadline.so: undefined reference to `tputs'
libreadline.so: undefined reference to`tgoto'
libreadline.so: undefined reference to `tgetflag'
libreadline.so: undefined reference to`UP'
libreadline.so: undefined reference to `tgetent'
libreadline.so: undefined reference to`tgetnum'
libreadline.so: undefined reference to `PC'
libreadline.so: undefined reference to`tgetstr'
libreadline.so: undefined reference to `BC'

These errors just dont seem to get away. I dont have administrative privileges and i cannot just do sudo yum install.
It will take a lot of channels to get them install any new packages,so is it possible to address this issue somehow ?

Answer (score 1):

I was facing the exact same problem. Found a solution provided by [Alex Wiltschko](https://github.com/alexbw/conda-lua-recipes#to-install-packages-warning-this-is-in-flux-quite-a-bit-might-not-be-current). In my case Anaconda was installed, so I could simply run the following command to install Lua and Torch:

```
conda install lua=5.2 lua-science -c alexbw
```

I have now posted the complete procedure on my blog. You can view the post [here](https://milindpadalkar.wordpress.com/2016/03/04/installing-torch-without-root-privileges/).

Regards,
Milind